# What is the easiest way to filter a changing number in a string?

Tags: java, regex

Can someone tell me the easiest way to extract the number '20' in the following substring.

Level I (10/20)

Note: The numbers in the brackets and the number behind 'Level' are changing and can contain more chars than in this example

It would be awesome if there is a method for using a regex and extract a specific part out of it.

Comment: I came here by mistake, by I guess `/(\d+)(?=\))/` regex is the one you are looking for

Comment: @ibowankenobi. Besides being in the wrong language, I'd say your answer was fine.

Comment: I know your question is asking about extraction, but I'm just wondering why? Unless you are hooking onto the output of a screen reader or something, you should be able to get the raw value from somewhere.

Comment: I am trying to extract those information out of an output file created by a software. Reading the output file is the easiest way for me to get them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not the best with regex, but here's a working solution for your example:

```
String s = "Level I (10/20)";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(\\d+/(\\d+)\\)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
20
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this one, works for multi-line input too:

```
^Level[[:blank:]].+\([\d]*\/([\d]*)\)
```

[Test here](https://regex101.com/r/iHj70F/3/)